# Writing 5 character to char[5] affects int

Tags: c, char, int, printf, scanf

Easy code down below.
Mac OS X 10.10.5, Xcode 7.2, C-file.
If I input 1, and afterwards qwert, I get 0 and qwert back.
1 and qwer gives 1 and qwer.
1 and e.g. qwerty gives 121 and qwerty.

- What have I missed - why can I write more than 4 chars (+null) to a 5 char variable?
- Why is the integer affected?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {   
    int userInput;
    char q[5];

    printf("Hello\n");
    scanf("%d", &userInput);
    printf("%d\nAnd\n", userInput);
    scanf("%s", q);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d\n%s", userInput, q);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior!!

Comment: `char q[5];` --> `char q[6];`. You forgot to allow room for string terminator after `qwerty` which is 5 characters, + 1 needed.

Comment: Because you're writing ***6*** characters to a char[5].

Comment: Hej, concerning "why can I write more than 4 chars (+null) to a 5 char variable?"  What did you expect should have happened?

Comment: I did not expect the printf to write out the whole input, but rather to just not read after the 4 first!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What have I missed - why can I write more than 4 chars (+null) to a 5 char variable?

There is nothing stopping you from accessing out of bounds portions of an array in `c`. This will compile:

```
char a[2];
a[10000] = 10;
```

> Why is the integer affected?

What you are causing is [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and is likely the reason that your `int` is affected. You can learn more about this by reading about [`c arrays`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm). This is happening because you are putting a 5 character string plus a null terminating character ( ie 6 `chars`) into a space only meant for 5. You are going outside the bounds of your array.

As a further note, `scanf("%s"` offers no method of protecting against this behavior. If a user puts in a string that is too long then too bad. That is why you should protect your input by using something like a format string of `"%4s"` or use [`fgets`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm):

```
fgets(q, sizeof q, stdin);
```

Which are both ways you can protect your input from entering more than 4 characters.

Comment: `scanf("%4s", q);` offers protection against this behaviour.

Comment: Better to use `fgets(q, sizeof q, stdin);`.  Note that input `qwert\n` will leave the `'\n'` in `stdin`.

Comment: @chux Yeah, i have edited thankyou. As for the second point, true, but not really part of the OP's real problem. I am sure they will come up against this in the future.

Answer (score 3):

[Edit] User/code *can* try to "write more than 4 chars (+null) to a 5 char variable".  C does not specify what should happen when code does not prevent such an event.  C is coding without the safety net/training wheels.

---

`scanf("%s", q);` reads and saves the 5 characters of `"qwert"` *and* it also appends a null character `'\0'`.  [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424737/writing-5-character-to-char5-affects-int/34424881#comment56591093_34424737)

Since `q[]` has only room to 5 characters, undefined behavior occurs (UB). In OP's case, it appear to have over-written `userInput`.

To avoid, use a width limit on `"%s"` such as below.  It will not consume more than 4 non-white-space from the user.  Unfortunately, extra text will remain in `stdin`.

```
char q[5];
scanf("%4s", q);
```

Or better, review `fgets()` for reading user input.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the int userInput is affected is that you are writing past the end of the char array (q).  Since both of these are stack variables, the compiler you're using seems to be allocating memory on the stack for the local variables in "reverse order", it, they are being "pushed" in the order defined, so the first local variable listed is lower on the stack.  So, in your case, when you write past the end of q, you are writing in the memory space allocated for userInput, which is why it is affected.